# How can i create a random graph such that the shortest path isn't usually a direct edge?

Tags: r

- Suppose that i have a graph with n vertices such that the graph is
  bi-partite , the flows are drawn using a uniform law and are positive
  !
- **If we consider the function L(i , j) that gives the flow of the    minimum path between the vertices i and j of the created random graph, I'm searching (i , j ) such that the function L reaches it maximum .**
- Using "igraph" i created an r function that generates some **random
  graph** , the first purpose is to **find all the shortests path** for
  that graph. After that , i will need the two vertices that are
  associated to the maximum of the flow matrix q1 ( The maximum of L )
  :
- **For any two vertices ( i , j ) , the matrix q1 gives the flow associated with the minimum path between **( i , j ).  The following code will find the maximum of L by finding the maximum of q1 :** **

.

```
sim_model<-function(number_vertices,min_val,max_val ){

#: Creating the graph F

n=number_vertices  # number of vertices 
F <- erdos.renyi.game(n, p.or.m=0.7, directed=FALSE)  #random graph bi-partite

m1=ecount(F) # edges number 
min = min_val    # 1 km
max = max_val   # 50 km 
run_unif = runif(m1 , min , max) #uniform law for flows/costs 

F <- set.edge.attribute(F, name="distance", value= run_unif )  # setting edges flows / costs
plot(F, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)  # plot F

q1=distances(F, weights = E(F)$distance) # flow matrix for all shortest paths between any two vertices
result1 = which(q1 == max(q1), arr.ind=TRUE) # The maximum possible flow for all shortests paths considering all vertices

associated_route_1=as.numeric(substr(get.all.shortest.paths(F, result1[2,][1], to = result1[2,][2])$`res`[[1]],0,7)) # the route corresponding to that maximum flow ( considering all the possible shortest paths only for any two vertices  )
}
```

**The problem :**

The code is working , the only issue is that `associated_route_1` variable is usually a direct edge between two vertices . This case is without any interest for me ! I'm wanting to know what could i do to avoid this .

I wish my request is clear , thank you for help !

Comment: I had found some occurences that gives me what i'm wanting like  :                                               `sim_model(40,15,180)`  and  `sim_model(40,80,180)`  but i don't know what this the reason